# How to allow screen size width if screen size is more then 900px below code is activated

Tags: jquery

```
<script>
$(function() {

var $sidebar   = $("#sidebar"), 
    $window    = $(window),
    offset     = $sidebar.offset(),
    topPadding = 50;

$window.scroll(function() {
    if ($window.scrollTop() > offset.top) {
        $sidebar.stop().animate({
            marginTop: $window.scrollTop() - offset.top + topPadding
        });
    } else {
        $sidebar.stop().animate({
            marginTop: 0
        });
    }
});

});
</script>
```

Comment: That's jQuery, not Java **[What are tags, and how should I use them?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging)**

Comment: sorry but i reall dnt know what it is, i just want to get idea to edit it using window size.. Sorry for my zero knowledge..

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
<script>
 if ($(window).width() >900) {
$(function() {

var $sidebar   = $("#sidebar"), 
    $window    = $(window),
    offset     = $sidebar.offset(),
    topPadding = 50;

$window.scroll(function() {
    if ($window.scrollTop() > offset.top) {
        $sidebar.stop().animate({
            marginTop: $window.scrollTop() - offset.top + topPadding
        });
    } else {
        $sidebar.stop().animate({
            marginTop: 0
        });
    }
});

});
}
</script>
```